# I can't install RPi-GPIO for windows in Pycharm

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I didn't install RPi-GPIO on my computer. You can see the log below. Can you help me, please? Firstly I installed MS build tools. But I couldn't solve this problem.
[Image.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngWOf.jpg)

Comment: Why do you want to install `RPi-GPIO` on Windows? What is the purpose?

Comment: I want to use with emulator not raspberry pi. I need to learn programming how to control mobile robot's wheels.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: What emulator are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot install `RPi.GPIO`, a library meant for Raspberry Pi computers running Linux, on Windows.